# Sort by not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM websites WHERE url LIKE '%.nl/' OR '%.com/' OR '%.org/' ORDER BY views DESC";
```

Outputs:

[image]

Where is this coming from?..

Comment: That code doesn't output anything. Where are you using `$query`?

Comment: I don't think your code is doing what you think. After each `OR`, you need to have a Boolean statement.  Your `WHERE` clause should probably be `WHERE url LIKE '%.nl/' OR url LIKE '%.com/' OR url LIKE '%.org/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Views is apparently a string so it is being sorted as a string. You will need to cast that field to an INT before using it for sorting purposes (and you should change the data type to INT permanently).

Comment: Damn, that's it... Clients used a varchar 255 for the MYSQL column -.- Thanks!